# How can I take back the iterator variable back to the first element of the list in Python after every iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

I want to know if it's possible to take back the iterator variable back to the first element in a list in Python after completing every iteration .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with a plain iterator to a list. Iterators are one-way: they can only be advanced forward.

If you need to be able to go back to the start, you have a few options:

- When you need to go back, abandon the iterator you're using and just use `iter` on the list to get a new one.
- You could use a helper like [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create an infinite iterator that produces the first element after it produces the last element. It "cycles" the iterator.